# Minimisation of thermodynamic potentials?

Tags: thermodynamics

An alternative formulation of the second law is that the energy of the system $U$ is minimised if the temperature and entropy of the system are held constant.

However, 
$$dU=TdS-pdV$$
which means that $U$ is presumably constant if the volume $V$ and the entropy $S$ are kept constant. How then can $U$ change so that it is minimised?

Comment: that is not an alternative formulation of the 2nd law but rather its consequence.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the answer to the question I asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write $dU=TdS-pdV$ you assume that there are only *two* state variables to describe the state of the system, here $S$ and $V$. Obviously when those are constant so is $U$ and then speaking of its minimum or maximum makes no sense. The issue of minimum comes up when the system can exchange more than one "work variables", say, electric or magnetic polarization, etc., or you have two systems, $dU_1 = T_1dS_1 - p_1dV_1$ and $dU_2 = T_2dS_2 - p_1dV_2$, and you demand that $V_1+V_2 = const$, that is $dV=0$, and also and $S_1+S_2 = const$, that is $dS=0$. Then it turns out that the equilibrium state that will evolve between the two systems when brought together to exchange entropy and volume work is characterized by $U=U_1+U_2$ being minimum.